# Show Type or typeOf in Idris?

Tags: idris

Is there a way to do something like `show Int`? I would like to be able to `show` records in the future, also.

What I'm trying to do is to write a function that prints it's type representation as a `String`, something like:

```
record Person where
  constructor Person
  name : String
  age : Int

>>> myFunction Person
"{ name : String, age : Int }"
```

In Haskell this would be easy to do with generics, but I'm not sure how to approach the problem in Idris.